# Error Converting Varchar To Numeric Within Case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that uses a series of temporary tables to pull data, format and then insert into a new table.  I know it does not make sense but I am trying to format out a null to either '' (blank) or a '-' dash.  This is bc. the value of zero actually represents a real balance.  When I do this I keep getting an error converting varchar to numeric.

```
CASE 
WHEN ##TEMPTABLE.[Summary Category Definition] = 'In Storage' THEN '' 
WHEN ##TEMPTABLE.[L/C Amount] > 0 THEN ##TEMPTABLE.[L/C Amount] 
ELSE ''
END AS [L/C Amount]
```

I have tried:

```
CASE 
WHEN ##TEMPTABLE.[Summary Category Definition] = 'In Storage' THEN '' 
WHEN ##TEMPTABLE.[L/C Amount] > 0 THEN convert(varchar(20), ##TEMPTABLE.[L/C Amount]    )
ELSE ''
END AS [L/C Amount]
```

is this even possible?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: post entire sql statement , not only the case

Comment: You can use `IsNumeric()` to attempt to determine whether the string contains a valid number before conversion.  Note that it is somewhat optimistic.  (Strange that the conversion in the title seems to be the reverse of that in the SQL shown.)

Comment: what data type is your column `[L/C Amount]`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your query shouldn't work unless the `[L/C Amount]` column is actually already a `VARCHAR`. In that case, you should change your statement for this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN ##TEMPTABLE.[Summary Category Definition] = 'In Storage' 
        THEN '' 
    WHEN ##TEMPTABLE.[L/C Amount] <> '0' 
        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ##TEMPTABLE.[L/C Amount]) -- why is this necessary?
    ELSE '' 
END AS [L/C Amount]
```

Comment: the enitre SQL Statement is huge l/c amount is actually in a temp table then loaded into a global temp table.  That global temp table is then loaded into a physical table but only after the data is formatted accordingly.  Perhaps the field in the global temp table is already varchar.  If it already a varchar how should i change the statement?  I am adding the convert to try to fix the error should I be changing it to numeric instead?

Comment: @user1991167 If it is already a `varchar`, then you should try the code I posted on my answer